# Unexpected token with Dialog command

Tags: dialog, command, sh, substitution

The dialog box as shown in https://bash.cyberciti.biz/wiki/index.php?title=A_progress_bar_(gauge_box)&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile does not work. Essentially I am trying to make a progress bar with a for command using dialog.

Each variation of the substitution does not to seem to work for the second example and I am unable to figure out why.

dialog --title "Copy file" --gauge "Copying file..." 10 75  < <(

Code goes here

)

Actual Results: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that it was using sh ./filename.sh to execute as opposed to bash.